# Chrome bookmark to execute a Windows program?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, bookmarks

At work I rely on a Flash-based admin tool. Traditionally this tool was hosted on a web server, but since Flash died, the company that owns the tool packaged it with Adobe Air so it can be installed locally. I'm used to opening a bookmark to open the tool, but now I have to open it from my start menu.

It would be convenient if I could have a bookmark that launches the local Air-packaged copy of the tool. Is this possible? I tried creating a bookmark like this:

```
file://C:/path/to/tool.exe
```

...but it tried to download it.

Is there a way to have a Chrome bookmark execute a Windows program?

Comment: Could you pin to your taskbar (run the software, right click on its name on the taskbar and select pin)? It will always be there and you won't even need to open Chrome.

Comment: @Anthony Of course, but the point is I'm used to opening it through Chrome. It's no big deal if I can't have a bookmark like that, but it would be more convenient. I also always have Chrome open (usually with 4-10 windows and a lot of tabs). I'm a web dev ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) to do this:

1. Copy the following into a `appurl.reg` file and run it.

   ```
   Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl]
   @="URL:AutoHotKey AppURL Protocol"
   "URL Protocol"=""

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\DefaultIcon]
   @="appurl.exe,1"

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\shell]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\shell\open]

   [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\shell\open\command]
   @="\"C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotKeyAppURL\\appurl.exe\" \"%1\""
   ```
2. Copy the following into a appurl.ahk file and save it.

   ```
   ; Application URL v1.0 by Jeff Sherk
   ;
   ; Will run a program that you pass in as a parameter (command line argument).
   ; Specifically created to be used with URL Protocol appurl://
   ;
   ; EXAMPLE:
   ;  You can type appurl://path/to/myapp.exe in the address bar of your browser to launch the application
   ;
   ; See these threads:
   ;  http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=477917
   ;  http://www.autohotkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=76997
   ;  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
   ;  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2330545/is-it-possible-to-open-custom-url-scheme-with-google-chrome
   ;
   ; Requires adding the following Registry Entry to work. You can copy and paste whats between the dashed lines
   ;  into a file called: appurl.reg  Just remember to remove all the semi-colons; at the beginning of the lines.
   ;-------------------------------------------------------------------
   ;Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

   ;[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl]
   ;@="URL:AutoHotKey AppURL Protocol"
   ;"URL Protocol"=""

   ;[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\DefaultIcon]
   ;@="appurl.exe,1"

   ;[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\shell]

   ;[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\shell\open]

   ;[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\appurl\shell\open\command]
   ;@="\"C:\\Program Files\\AutoHotKeyAppURL\\appurl.exe\" \"%1\""
   ;-------------------------------------------------------------------

   if 0 != 1 ;Check %0% to see how many parameters were passed in
   {
       msgbox ERROR: There are %0% parameters. There should be 1 parameter exactly.
   }
   else
   {
       param = %1%  ;Fetch the contents of the command line argument

       appurl := "appurl://" ; This should be the URL Protocol that you registered in the Windows Registry

       IfInString, param, %appurl%
       {
           arglen := StrLen(param) ;Length of entire argument
           applen := StrLen(appurl) ;Length of appurl
           len := arglen - applen ;Length of argument less appurl
           StringRight, param, param, len ; Remove appurl portion from the beginning of parameter
       }

       Run, %param%

   }
   ```
3. Convert `appurl.ahk` to `appurl.exe` by compiling it with the [compiler included with AHK](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe).
4. Move the `.exe` to `C:\Program Files\AutoHotKeyAppURL`.

Now you can launch any program by typing the following in the address bar `appurl://path/to/myapp`

Example:

```
appurl://C:/WINDOWS/system32/notepad.exe
```

**Edit**: to support paths that contain spaces, add `file:///` before the file path:

```
appurl://file:///C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

You can save it as a bookmark too.

Source:  [Application URL - Launch local application from browser](https://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/71831-application-url-launch-local-application-from-browser/)

Comment: Wow, that's actually a brilliant answer. Thankfully I no longer feel the need to launch programs from a browser bookmark, but if I did, I would do it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Nice article, thanks

I am using it to run a pdf editor and I need to add another argument.

I am some trouble but not clear if trouble is on ahk only and / or also in the url

I compiled using version 1

I need to run something like this

appurl://file:///C:\myapps\appurl.exe c:\myapp\n++\notepad++.exe my file with space.txt

with your code I am able to open notepad++.exe but I am not able to add a new parameter

appurl.exe reports 1 argument because from url no space but %20

msgbox of param show this one
file:///C:%5myapps%5Cnotepad++.exe%20%22C:%5CTEMP%5Cmy%0file%20with%20 space.txt

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1239535)